# cocoAspell successor? (Improved Spell Check for m1+, macOS 13+)

Tags: system-settings, spellcheck

`cocoAspell` (*[git](https://github.com/leuski/cocoAspell), last updated: 2016, deprecated*) brought the unix package `Aspell` (a spellcheck dictionary for terminal editors) to the system-wide macOS spellcheck.

`cocoAspell` has since deprecated.

---

**Questions**:

- Is improving the default macOS spellcheck dictionary still as desirable as it once was?
- Is there any alternative means to bring such an improved spellcheck dictionary (such as `Aspell`) to the system-wide macOS spellcheck?

---

I read [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/402822/locating-the-file-in-which-a-dictionary-word-is-stored) that macOS now uses `Hunspell` and `AppleSpell` as spellcheck tools. (I couldn't call `Hunspell` from the terminal; does that mean it doesn't exist or that I simply cannot access system packages by default?)

- Could a package such as `enchant` perform this?

Comment: Can't help you, but cocAspell looks cool as heck, thanks for turning me onto a new project. (I'm on an old OS so the deprecation is okay.)

Comment: Unless the underlying NSSpellServer apis have been removed (which they don't seem to) it should still work? Have you tried compiling from source?

Comment: Also +1 to Wowfunhappy's comment, I honestly didn't even know this was possible. I knew of the semi-obscure trick of adding your own hunspell dictionary, but that OSX had an entire API to provide your own spell server is simply mind-blowing. It honestly surprises me how many tiny obscure corners Cocoa has. See http://macoscope.com/blog/how-not-to-create-a-spell-server-for-mac-os-x/ for more info on spell servers.